# How can I receive notifications from a web site loaded in a WebView in my app in Notification Center?

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

I am creating an Mac app with a WebView that loads a website that can send web notifications. I want these notifications to appear in the notification center. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you don't want to send notifications yourself from your app, but you want to allow web notifications sent by a website encapsulated in your app's WebView to appear as they do with Safari. Is that right?

If so, the [Notification Programming Guide for Websites](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html) seems to answer this in the first few paragraphs. They make a distinction between *push* notifications and *local* notifications. Push notifications are sent at any time, whether you're browsing the website or not; local notifications are invoked by JavaScript from the loaded web page while you're browsing. Push notifications happen outside any app and you don't have to do anything extra; local notifications have to be set up (with JavaScript on the website), per the guide. Nothing further appears to be necessary, aside from the user allowing notifications from that site or any sites.

It's unclear from the guide whether you can (or even have to) handle this from a WebView in your own app, but the guide specifies the notification object is provided by WebKit (the engine behind Safari and your own app's WebView), so I guess it *should* work. Have you tried it already?

Armed with this information, I recommend reading the guide thoroughly and trying it. If you run into problems, edit your post (if you can - I notice you're a new SO user; if you can't, post it as a comment and someone can help get it into the body of your post), and include a detailed description of the steps you took to try this, as well as the relevant code (including the JavaScript from the website), and what exactly does or doesn't happen. This will help us help you.

Comment: I do not understand how to implement this in my Mac OS application it is not written. For example, I have a webview of WhatsApp, I do not understand how to retrieve notifications in the Notification Center

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen I don’t know either. What have you tried? What worked and what didn’t? I suggest posting your own separate question and providing as much detail about what you’ve tried so far as you can. Help us help you.

Comment: I've posted post with more details, can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216918/switf-cocoa-how-to-handle-notification-from-webview-to-display-it-into-local